# Optimized "Coordinated Charge"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, charge

> When an ally with this feat charges a creature that is no further away from you than your speed, you can, as an immediate action, charge that creature. You must be able to follow all of the normal charge rules.

The normal charge rules say charging takes time... this feat says it's immediate.

A lvl 4 rogue scout gets to sneak attack whenever he charges.

A cavalier is basically built on charging, and can ride through (right on by the enemy) when charging. Also his speed is quite high, so the feat could trigger almost whenever the rogue charges.

So round 1 first cavalier charges and rides through, rogue is still too far away to join. Then rogue charges on his turn, feat triggers, immediately cavalier charges again? Then the rogue spends the next round running away to get a little distance, the cavalier charges, feat triggers rogue gets to join?

What about two cavaliers? That would get really crazy!
Doesn't that basically ruin the action economy or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You don't actually need to put "Pathfinder" at the beginning of your question titles. The question has a Pathfinder tag that will show up everywhere the question does - this already conveys it's a Pathfinder question

Comment: there is some discussion on the feat here: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mqyq?Coordinated-Charge-Am-I-reading-this-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It costs you your immediate action (which you only get 1 of each round), so you are limited 1 'free' charge per character per round. This charge is at the expense of any swift or immediate actions you might want to take.

It also has some high prerequisites: +10 bab + 2 other teamwork feats. Since these are teamwork feats, both the rogue and the cavalier need the coordinated charge feat, and thus have to spend the 3 feats for it.

So for a high investment you get something pretty powerful.

It should be noted that without multiclassing, the rogue will not qualify for this feat until 14th level. At that level, you should have access to abilities/spells that make it so your sneak attack damage will be applied to both attacks of your full round attack, possibly making that the more desired route to optimize.

The problems with taking this feat are the same problems with normal charging: difficult terrain, curved hallways, friendly/unfriendly obstacles in the way, -2AC.

Comment: Well, a cavalier with +10 BAB will already have 2 bonus teamwork feats.  :)  However, the BAB prereq means they couldn't use their tactician ability with it until 17th level at the earliest.  (Though I guess taking a level of Fighter/etc would let you do it at 10th!)

Comment: if the rogue does not have to build for this except for being a scout, it makes it much more useful and I can see it actually seeing play.